# Directshow Issue Running 2 Graphs

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture, multiple-instances

I have Mp4 Capture Application in direct show. In my application i need to capture 30 min(or say some dynamic value) video continuously .  my graph is as below

```
Video Source --> x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec --------->GDCL MPEG-4 Multiplexer --> File Writer                                             
                                                        | 
Audio Source --> ACM Wrapper --> Monogram AAC Encoder --|
```

For that i have made logic like -->

1. capture class which contains all the required things to make graph
   Builder , get  Devices , Build Graph , start and stop capture graph.
2. make 2 pointer objects for capture class and build graph for 1st and
   2nd objects.
3. run the 1st graph and after 30 min timeout , start 2nd graph and
   stop 1st graph

run the graph in same manner continuously , i guess this logic should work properly... and at almost logically is correct

when i build 1st it 1st graph generated successfully , and using 2nd pointer object i build graph for that object , it do not connect `Audio Source Pin` and `ACM Wrapeer` with `HRESULT = -2147220969`

Anybody have idea for such behavior??

I can paste my code if needed.

Thanks.

@Roman R. , i am editing my post to add a fragment of my code , i hope i added the required details here.

**EDIT:**

```
// Create 1st Capture Instance
Capture *capodd = new Capture();
capodd->destination = capinfo.destination;
capodd->periodicity = capinfo.periodicity;

// Select 1st Audio and 1st Video Device from Devices add their filters to graph
capodd->SelectDevice(1,1);

// Build Graph for the 1st Capture Instance
capodd->BuildMp4CaptureGraph();

// Create 2nd Capture Instance
Capture *capeven = new Capture();
capeven->destination = capinfo.destination;
capeven->periodicity = capinfo.periodicity;

// Select 1st Audio and 1st Video Device from Devices add their filters to graph
capeven->SelectDevice(1,1);

// Build Graph for the 2nd Capture Instance
capeven->BuildMp4CaptureGraph();


while(1)
{
    // set current capture file 
    Capture *capcurrent = new Capture();
    if(!capodd.Fcapturing && !capeven.Fcapturing)
    {
        capcurrent = capodd
        capodd->StopCapture();
    }
    else if(capodd.Fcapturing)
    {
        capcurrent = capeven;
        capodd->StopCapture();
    }
    else
    {
        capcurrent = capodd;
        capeven->StopCapture();
    }



    // Set the Capture File name 
    capcurrent->setCaptureInfo();

    // start capturing
    capcurrent->StartCapture();

    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123;
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        capcurrent->ErrMsg(TEXT("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

     hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        capcurrent->ErrMsg(TEXT("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Set a timer to call the timer routine in 10 seconds.
    if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue, 
        (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerRoutine, &arg , (capcurrent->dwTimeLimit)*1000, 0, 0))
    {
        capcurrent->ErrMsg(TEXT("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (WaitForSingleObject(gDoneEvent, ((capcurrent->dwTimeLimit)*1000)+1000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        capcurrent->ErrMsg(TEXT("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(gDoneEvent);

    // Delete all timers in the timer queue.
    if (!DeleteTimerQueue(hTimerQueue))
        capcurrent->ErrMsg(TEXT("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());


}
```

Select device get the audio and video filter devices and add selected filter to graph

BuildMp4CaptureGraph created the graph as of above diagram , ACM Wrapper , GDCL Mux filters are created and addded to graph from this method using CoCreateInstance

I guess that some of the resource need to be released externally , not sure.

Comment: Have you considered using only 1 graph? Just stop it at 30 min, change output file name and start it again?

Comment: yes , we had done that.. but i looses about 100ms to 150ms  data. but we need very high accuracy

Answer (score 1):

`-2147220969` -> `0x80040217` -> `VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT`:

> No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection.

That is, your attempt to build the graph second time failed. You need to check what filters you have on the graph to isolate the error to specific pin connection.

Also note that you cannot typically use the same capture device in 2+ graphs, they are exclusively locked by active pipelines.

Comment: Thanks @Roman R. , for your reply, i saved the graph that build using my application , i have all the filters as above graph in my question , which of them All video Capture filters connected and Audio Capture filters are not connected , after closing my application , i can able to connect `Audio Source Pin` and `ACM Wrapeer` manually. so is this can be the issue for locking of device resourses?? but if it is the case then my video capture graph also should not connect , but they get connected. what's your thought??

Comment: So you see the broken connection, and it caused the failure. This is for you to start troubleshooting from. As I mentioned exclusive locks are likely to take place. Also be sure to create capture filters through monikers (not CoCreateInstance).

Comment: Thanks @Roman R. for your reply... well i was troubleshooting this issue from 2 days , still didn't get any reason or way to solve this :( :( , i am creating video and audio capture filters using monikers... do we need to create `ACM Wrapper` and other audio filters using monikers only??

and one more thing... i also tried with stop 1st graph and then build and run 2nd graph, they also i get the same error?? in this case , as 1st graph is not using resource then it should allow the second graph to run... but its not happening?? any suggestion on that??

Comment: OK, perhaps if you could post a code fragment where you create second graph, this could be helpful.

Comment: hi @Roman R. actual code is very big , i am using `Directshow's AMCap` Code as reference. so , `StartCapture` And `StopCapture` methods are same of it. I have put `TimerQueue` for capture desired video and on `Timer Signal` , i first `StopCapture` for first graph,  and then do `StartCapture` for second graph. I edit the post and some of code there.